# Numbers or Excel, Sum data in a column depending on date

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers

[image]

I hope to Sum Column Y based on data in column A. That is, If A is in (contains) "July", then sum Y. i.e. "What are the totals for July?

Comment: (1) Look at `SUMIF`.  (2) Just because you can post a screenshot doesn't mean you should.  Please post spreadsheet data as text.  Obviously you don't have to include columns B through X if they aren't relevant.

Comment: Super User is not a "do it for you" site. We will help you with it. Please tell us what you have already attempted. Sharing the formula you are currently using, along with any errors, is very helpful.